# Problema con checkboxes en DataTables jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy trabajando con DataTables de jQuery, lo que hago es incluir checkboxes a cada fila, para que se pueda seleccionar varias filas a la vez, los checxbox tickeados de una página me muestra su ID de esas 10 primeras filas, pero cambio a la otra página, y al volver a hacer que me muestre los checkbox seleccionados, me muestra como si no se hubiera seleccionado.

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer para que me muestre todos los checkboxes seleccionados, de varias paginas del DataTable?

Este es mi DataTable:

```
var otables = $('#doctables').dataTable(
{ "aLengthMenu":[20, 60,80],

    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "bProcessing": true, 
    " bServerSide": true,
      "scrollY":"400px",
      "sScrollX": '100%',
      "sScrollXInner": "100%",
      "bScrollCollapse": true,
     "ajax": {
                  "type": "POST",
                  "url": "../ctrl/datos.php"
                },
    "bPaginate": true, 
    "bFilter": true, 
    "bInfo": true, 
    "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
     //creando los cehckbox en  la columna 0
    $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html( '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="'+aData[0]+'" class="checkbox" value='+aData[0]+'>');
     }
    });
```

y con este botón quiero ver los `value` de los *checkbox* seleccionados:

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
       $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
                  alert($(this).val());

        });
});
```

como mi DataTable está paginado por 20 filas, selecciono 3 valores de la primera página y me muestra bien; pero al cambiar a los siguintes 20 filas y selecciono otro, solo me muestra el valor seleccionado de esas últimas 20 filas y no así las anteriores.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Sé que no es el mismo problema de [esta otra pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16845/ocultar-checkbox-en-jquery-datatables), pero se parece en esencia, y las soluciones puede que te ayuden como guía. En tu caso específico, comparte algo de código con lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora, será más fácil ayudarte así

Comment: @SergioDenAlmendras, por favor, actualiza tu pregunta, no coloques código en los comentarios _ya que estos son temporales._ Esta [información](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) te ayudará a comprender cómo puedes generar una pregunta mas clara para que así podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Me tocó pasar por lo mismo, espero y este snippet te solvente el problema a ti o a futuros usuarios.

```
var rows = $(('#datatable')
   .rows({ 'search': 'applied' })
   .nodes()).filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)');//busca todos los registros del datatable

rows.each(function(index,elem){
   //cada row es un tr
     console.log($('datatable').row(elem).data());
});
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola, tengo el mismo problema sin embargo no he podido solucionarlo con tu codigo, por favor me podrias guiar

Comment: Que versión de datatables estás usando?

Comment: la version actual, estoy usando la CDN  que dan en los ejemplos.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wolffhelm/9y3x6me6/  A ver si así, usé igual el de CDN.

Comment: No funciona tu código, me marca error: ".rows no es una función"

Comment: sube un jsfiddle con tu codigo para darle una revisada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo hice para que no fuera tan complicado fue lo siguiente

```html
arr_b=new Array();
function removeItemFromArr ( arr, item ) {
                var i = arr.indexOf( item );
arr.splice( i, 1 );
}
            $('input[type=checkbox]').change( function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
                    console.log("Checkbox " + $(this).prop("id") +  " (" + $(this).val() + ") => Seleccionado");
                    arr_b.push($(this).val());
                } else {
                    console.log("Checkbox " + $(this).prop("id") +  " (" + $(this).val() + ") => Deseleccionado");
                    removeItemFromArr(arr_b,$(this).val());
                }
            });
$('#imprimir').click(function(){
    console.log("click array arr_b leng:",JSON.stringify(arr_b));
});
```

Coloco un array luego el id del checkbox evaluo si se seleciona o no y voy insertando cada valor del checkbox o eliminandolo segun su selección, luego lo imprimo con un click en un boton